# how to implement live chat in iphone using XMPP framework?

Tags: iphone, xmpp, chat, livechat

i want to implement chat functionality in my iphone application.For that i want
to use XMPP framework.for that i have checked the tutorial how to integrate xmapp
in phone application.
http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/iPhone
but from where can i download xmpp framework i have checked this link
in google code http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/downloads/list but there are no
download available.can anyone also suggest tutorial or any sample code that builds
chat application using xmpp?

Answer (score 2):

**Installation:**

you can download the framework from here

http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/checkout using a mercurial client for your OS.

or

download files individually from

http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/browse/

After this use

http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/iPhone

to install the sdk

**For the mercurial client:**

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads/

**Usage:**

http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/IntroToFramework offers some good instructions on use

Comment: Your link not work there is google 403 error so please delete this answer